# How would I make a function that searches through a .txt file for a title?

Tags: c++

Started learning C++ a couple months ago, and I've been working on a program in my spare time that (among other things) searches through a .txt file containing video game titles and the console its on, but I can't figure out how to search through the file. For some reason, the string "user_search" when combined with strings divider " - " and console, it doesn't include what the user actually searched. My thought was that it only searched the first word in the title, so I tried using getline() to retrieve the entire user_search INCLUDING whitespace, but no dice. Also thought maybe my nothing was found b/c it only searched the title and not "user_search - console" so I tried to make a for loop where on each iteration, the line  in the .txt would be stored as a string and would be compared with the full user_search with the divider and title also to no luck. Any help/improvements someone could offer would be helpful. Thank you!

Code in question:

```
 int main()
{
    int choice;
    int line_number{ line_counter() };
    string new_game;
    string game_list;
    string name_add;
    string user_add;
    string exit_cmd = "exit" "Exit";
    string console;
    string divider = " - ";
    
    line_counter();

    string again = "Search for another?";
    string menu_greeting = "Welcome to my game library! Please choose from one of the following options:\n";
    string menu_options = "1.) Get a game's genre and the console it is on.\n2.) Add a new game to the list!\n3.) Check your inventory!\n4.) How many games do I have?\n";

    cout << menu_greeting << menu_options;
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:   //search through text file "game_list.txt" line-by-line for a game title//
    {
        int line_number{ line_counter() }; //returns number of lines in the list a.k.a. how many games there are total//
        int i;
        string game_name;
        string search_greeting; //text//
        string search_success; //text//
        string search_failure;//text//
        string console;
        string user_search;
        string line;
        string divider = " - ";
        string query;

        search_greeting = "What game are you searching for?\n";
        search_success = user_search, "is on the ", console, "console.\n";
        again = "Search again?\n", "Y/N\n";
        search_failure = "Game was not found in your list, maybe add it in?\n";


        cout << "What game are you searching for?" << endl;
        cin >> user_search;
        cout << "What console is it on?"<<endl;
        cin >> console;
        getline(cin, user_search);
        game_name =  user_search + divider + console;
        query = user_search + divider + console;
        fstream game_list;
        game_list.open("game_list.txt", ios::in); //read from game_list.txt//
        line_counter();

        for (i = 0; i < line_number; i++)
        {
            cout << "Looking for: " << user_search << endl;
            cout << game_name << endl;
        
            
                game_name == line;
                if (game_name == query)
                {
                    cout << search_success;
                }

            
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is the fact that the shown code doesn't even read anything from the file, at all? And what does the `line_counter()` function do, that's called so many times, all the time? Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted.

Comment: I see input from `cin >> variable;` being used without testing for success: you should **always** test whether input was successful before using the result, e.g., e.g., using `if (!(cin >> variable)) { deal_with_input_error(); }`.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a program it is a good idea not to put everything in main but to add a bit more structure to your program by making data structures and functions and by using functions from the standard library.

Here is a an example to get you started. The function you are looking for is implemented in find_game_by_title

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// simulated file content
std::istringstream file_stream
{
    "Halo,Xbox\n"
    "Doom,Pc\n"
    "Final fantasy,Playstation\n"
};

// group all properties of a game in a struct
// it is always good to model/group things that 
// have a close relation in a class or struct.
struct game_t
{
    std::string title;
    std::string console;
};

// when looking for a game it can be found or not found
// and if found store a copy of it 
// (no pointers or references for now, this is to get you started)
struct search_result_t
{
    bool found = false;
    game_t game;
};

// make a class so you can keep all loaded data 
// in memory and do operations on it.
class game_library_t
{
public:

    // function that can load data from any stream
    // this includes std::ifile and std::istringstream
    explicit game_library_t(std::istream& is)
    {
        game_t game;

        // get game title from line up till first ',', get console from rest of line until newline
        while (std::getline(is, game.title, ',') && std::getline(is, game.console))
        {
            // add a copy of game to the vector
            m_games.push_back(game);
        }
    }

    search_result_t find_game_by_title(const std::string& title)
    {
        // std::find_if is a standard library implementation you can reuse to look for things.
        // you do need to help it by providing a function that returns true if there is a match

        // the third parameter in the call to find_if is called a lambda function
        // https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-lambdas-anonymous-functions/
        // they are often used in calls to the standard library

        auto it = std::find_if(m_games.begin(), m_games.end(), [&](const game_t& game)
            {
                return (game.title == title);
            });

        // the next line sets 
        // result.found to (it != m_games.end()) meaning the iterator found something
        // result.title to the found title
        search_result_t result{ it != m_games.end(), *it };
        return result;
    }

private:
    // std::vector is an array that can grow at runtime
    std::vector<game_t> m_games;

};

int main()
{
    // todo load actual file content first using std::ifile.
    game_library_t library{ file_stream };

    // then setup your menu to make choices.

    search_result_t result = library.find_game_by_title("Halo");

    if (result.found)
    {
        std::cout << "Game '" << result.game.title << "' found, you have it on : " << result.game.console << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```